# preg_match all the occurrences in a line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**Example (file=xref.tex)**:

```
This is a example string and first line with <xref>id1</xref>then,<xref>id2</xref>and with no line breaks<xref>id3</xref>.
This is a second line which has <xref>id4</xref>
```

**Example (file=id)**:

```
id1 eqvalue1
id2 eqvalue2
id3 eqvalue3
id4 eqvalue4
```

**Requirement:** Every unique id has a equivalent value. I need to replace that equivalent value in the place of id in each occurrences in "xref.tex" file.

**Tried so far:**

```
    $xref=file("xref.tex");
    $idfile=file("id");
    for($y=0;$y<count($xref);$y++){
      for($z=0;$z<count($idfile);$z++){
        $idvalue=explode(" ",$idfile[$z])//exploding based on space charac
        $id1=$idvalue[0]; //this is equivalent value of unique id
        $id2=$idvalue[1];  // this is unique id
        preg_match( '/<xref>(.*?)<\/xref/', $xref[$y], $match );
        //getting the content between "<xref>"and "</xref>"
        if($match[1]===$id2{
          $xref[$y]=str_replace($match[1],$id1,$xref[$y]);}
          //here first occurrence of id is replaced. how to replace  
          //second occurrence of id in a line as  
          //preg_match( '/<xref>(.*?)<\/xref/', $xref[$y], $match )
          //this regex focusing on first occurrence only every time.
          //???? prob here is how can i do this logic in all the occurrences 
          //in each line 
        }
     }
   }
```

**Expected output:**

```
This is a example string and first line with <xref>eqvalue1</xref>then,<xref>eqvalue2</xref>and with no line breaks<xref>eqvalue3</xref>.
This is a second line which has <xref>eqvalue4</xref>
```

Comment: `preg_match_all()`, you're welcome!

Comment: why not file_get_contents and preg_replace?

Comment: I have to replace different value to each occurrences. After I replaced value into first occurrence how to focus on second occurrence and so on in a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I understand. The contents of the file **xref.tex** is as follows

```
<xref>id1</xref><xref>id2</xref><xref>id3</xref><xref>id4</xref> //line 1
<xref>id2</xref><xref>id3</xref> //line 2
<xref>id4</xref> //line 3
... and so on
```

First of all, you have to fix the regex. You're missing `>` at the end of it. It should be

```
/<xref>(.*?)<\/xref>/
```

Then you need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` as suggested.

I've modified the code a little bit. This should also work if you have same id repeating in a single line.

```
$xref=file("xref.tex");
$idfile=file("id");
for($y=0;$y<count($xref);$y++)
{
    preg_match_all( '/<xref>(.*?)<\/xref/', $xref[$y], $match ); //get all matches and store them in *match*
    for($z=0;$z<count($idfile);$z++)
    {
        $idvalue=explode(" ",$idfile[$z]);
        $id1=$idvalue[0]; 
        $id2=$idvalue[1];  
        //Below, we're replacing all the matches in line with corresponding value. Edit: Maybe not the best way, but it will give you an idea.
        foreach($match[0] as $matchItem)
            $xref[$y]=str_replace($matchItem,$id1,$xref[$y]);
    }    
}
```

**EDIT**

You might want to check [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). I think that would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file "id" as space separated csv to an array and then use that array with preg_replace on the other file as string using file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$re = "/(<xref>[^\\d]+)(\\d)(<\\/xref)/m";
$str = "This is a example string and first line with <xref>id1</xref>then,<xref>id2</xref>and with no line breaks<xref>id3</xref>. This is a second line which has <xref>id4</xref>";
$subst = "$1eqvalue$2$3";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW9lG6/1)

Comment: Actually "id1" and "eqvalue1" is just an example. If it is like "heng-etal2007" and "bibr8" . How to do it in each occurrences?. From the id value I will get equivalent value from other file and replace it in the place of id